# Trigger Autosave or disable unsaved changes dialog

Tags: plugins, autosave

As the title says, I want to trigger the autosave function of wordpress manually or just disable the "unsaved changes" dialog.

The reason for this: I'm developing a plugin which reloads the post edit page after doing some stuff and it's just annoying that the "unsaved changes" popup always pops up before reloading.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable it with: [source](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-hook-disable-posts-auto-saving)

```
function disableAutoSave(){
    wp_deregister_script('autosave');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'disableAutoSave' );
```

Also not a real answer, edit the interval in the WP-config:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Modify_AutoSave_Interval

The autosave function itself is in `wp-includes/js/autosave(.dev).js`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't really help me since I don't want to turn of the auto save function. I'll have a look at the js file and see what I can do.

Comment: Yes I know :( I'm pretty sure the answer is in the js file but I'm not very skilled in JS so I can't figure it out. You might be able to trigger `autosave()` a function that might work